# ClamAV discovered malware in a Flatpak app - how do I determine which app it is?

Tags: flatpak, clamav

During a ClamAV scan, malware was found in the following Flatpak file:

```
/home/daniel/.local/share/flatpak/repo/objects/34/32b76db9f3df9ffb126a55624df56417c367c47d95e3f619585af51e448144.file: BC.Gif.Exploit.Agent-1425366.Agent FOUND
```

I'm not sure what app this was from. How do I find out?

This is after a new OS install (about 1 month ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same.

This discussion reports it as a false positive:
https://discourse.flathub.org/t/clamscan-and-flathub/1099